# Mysql 5.1 - Error Add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am running MySQL 5.1.54-lubuntu4

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `mcli` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `pr_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK7617032AB07F537D` (`id`),
  KEY `FK7617032A4007E4D7` (`pr_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK7617032AB07F537D` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `acli` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And this table has data in it.

I have another table

```
CREATE TABLE `PR` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `frequency` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FKPRtoAR` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKPRtoAR` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `AR` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

This table also has data in it.

The data in all the rows of mcli.pr_id (table mcli, field id) are valid entries in pr.id (because that is what they used to be in another table OLDPPR before I migrated OLDPR table to PR. In fact mcli.pr_id used to have a foreign key to OLDPR.id (the id field of the old table).

I want to add a foreign key constraint which ties mcli.pr_id to PR.id. As you can see from the schema, I have already created an index on mcli.pr_id called FK7617032A4007E4D7. So I tried to run the command to generate a foreign key constraint.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `mcli` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK7617032A4007E4D7` FOREIGN KEY (`pr_id`) REFERENCES `PR` (`id`);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT `FK7617032A4007E4D7` FOREIGN KEY (`pr_id`) REFERENCES ' at line 1
mysql>
```

I also tried flushing all of the data from mcli and re-running the command to add the foreign key constraint but it still gave the same error. I tried single quotes and no quotes.  Everything on the web suggests that I have the right syntax. What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an educated guess, I don't have the environment to test it.

The parser could be confused by the fact that there is already a key with the same name, this is known to cause syntax errors also, even when, strictly speaking, the *syntax* is fine.

Try using another constraint name, just to verify the behavior.

Then, try to drop this key:

```
KEY `FK7617032A4007E4D7` (`pr_id`),
```

before adding the constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE `mcli` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK7617032A4007E4D7` FOREIGN KEY (`pr_id`) REFERENCES `PR` (`id`);
```

I could not reproduce this on a more recent 5.1 version.

Comment: I tried that. I also tried dropping the "ADD CONSTRAINT" clause. It worked sometimes but not every time. My eventual workaround was to clone the child table, drop the original child table, create the original child table name, and bring back the data from the clone.